# TextView added programmatically doesn't reset to beginning of screen on new line

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-viewholder

I'm adding programmatically TextViews in a ViewHolder which is added in a RecyclerView. The problem I'm facing is after it reaches the end of the screen and goes to new line the text is not align from the beginning of the screen.

```
        mHolder.mAuthorsContainer.removeAllViews();
        int size = mData.mAuthors.mAuthorsHMap.size(), count = 1;
        Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(mContext, R.font.zillaslab_bold);
        
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mData.mAuthors.mAuthorsHMap.entrySet()) {
           String key = entry.getKey();
           String value = entry.getValue();

           TextView mAuthor_ = new TextView(mContext);
           mAuthor_.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3100A2"));
           mAuthor_.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           mAuthor_.setTypeface(typeface);
           mAuthor_.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, CustomPreferences.getInstance(mContext).getmSpArticlePublishSize());
           mAuthor_.setLineSpacing(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, CustomPreferences.getInstance(mContext).getmSpArticleTextLineSpacing(), mMetrics), 1.0f);

           mAuthor_.setText(value);

           mHolder.mAuthorsContainer.addView(mAuthor_);

    }
```

mAuthorsContainer is a LinearLayout and the parent layout is ConstraintLayout, that's all

Tried setLines, setMaxLines, setGravity to left, nothing works so far.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you should just use a single `TextView` and add all the text to it. If you need individual views for some reason, look into Google's `FlexboxLayout` to support this "line-wrapping" concept.

Comment: Thank you @BenP. ! I actually needed the individual views for onClick action and just used FlexboxLayout, it works like a charm ! Cheers mate.